# lightning:radioGroup is allowing multi-select

Tags: lightning-aura-components, multi-select, bug, radio-button, radiogroup

I have a `lightning:radioGroup` that shows record types for an object:

```
<aura:attribute name="recordTypes" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordTypeValue" type="String"/>

<lightning:radioGroup options="{!v.recordTypes}" value="{!v.recordTypeValue}" required="true"/>
```

In my controller I populate the recordTypes list with unique label-value pairs.

The radio buttons and their labels show up nicely. However, suddenly they become multi-selectable:

- select option1 > select option2 > select option1 (now both options are selected)

When I debug recordTypeValue I can see 2 Ids written into it. I am not seeing any attributes on the said component that allows me to enable/disable multi-selecting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've forgotten a required attribute. The radioGroup is grounded in HTML's `<input type="radio" />`, which uses a "name" attribute to determine groups. If you forget to specify the name, the options actually behave like independent radio groups. The following change is necessary for proper operation:

```
<lightning:radioGroup name="recordTypes" options="{!v.recordTypes}" value="{!v.recordTypeValue}" required="true" />
```

Where "name" should be unique to each lightning:radioGroup within the component.

Note: The documentation lists "name" as optional; this is clearly a developer/documentation oversight, because without a name, this component won't work as expected.

Comment: That solved it! But I don't get why going from option1 to option2 worked (i.e. option1 was deselected)..

Comment: @Mossi Might have been your browser. When I tried it, going from option1 to option2 resulted in both being selected.